# run .sh script via Jenkins to execute aws command error

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-s3

my problem is that i try to execute **shell script to copy** created files from msbuild to **AWS s3** via **Jenkins**.

Then i add new build step "Execute Shell" and set to execute shell script by command: sh publishS3.sh nothing happens and files doesn't apper in s3 bucket.
my Jenkins use Local Windows Server.

Then i try to execute the shell script by typing  sh publishS3.sh in Jenkins local directory all ok , files was copyed secessfully to s3 bucket , but if i try to do it from jenkins nothing was happen. My publishS3.sh script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
aws s3 cp  Com.VistaDraft.Common.dll s3://download.vistadraft.com/MVP
```

i was tryed to to check witch output i receive after execute by adding at the end command > output.txt but Jenkins generate an empty file. If i try to do the same locally i was receive an message that i secessfully copyed files to s3. i Set the shell script path of jenkins C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe and using git-bash.exe locally too. Maybe whom know where is a problem ? Please suggest.

Comment: If the command generates an error, it might not generate anything on stdout, so you need to capture stderr too with `command > output.txt 2>&1`. In general, make sure Jenkins / the Jenkins job has the right credentials to access the bucket

Comment: @arco444 it helps to solve problem !!! I just added aws path to enviromental variables and all ok !! Please add your coment to answer i accept it !

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add `-ex` in the first line of the script to allow you to see what it's doing and ease the debugging:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
# rest of script
```

Make sure the `aws` tool is in the PATH of the environment where Jenkins runs your script. It might help if you specify full path to the command.

You could put `which aws` in your script to see what's going on.

Comment: #!/bin/bash -ex doesn't helps :( and i try to put which aws and it's /c/Program Files/Amazon/AWSCLI/aws it locally , but if i add which aws > test.txt at the end of the script  and execute it from jenkins it generate an empty test.txt file.